# Apply multi-parameter function using multiprocessing to generate pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I recently started to use `multiprocessing` when mapping some complex functions on pandas dataframe. For example if I want to create a new column based on a value of some other column, I could do:

```
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')

import multiprocessing as mp

#example of a "complex function" returning some array
def function_1(val_):
    return [1] * round(val_)

with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
    iris['test_1'] = pool.map(function_1, iris['petal_length'])
```

This is much faster than using just `apply` with `lambda function`.

If I have a function which takes as an input multiple other columns of a dataframe (plus even some parameters), I could normally apply it like this:

```
def function_2(val_1, val_2, param_):
    return [param_] * round(val_1 + val_2)


iris['test_2'] = iris.apply(lambda x: function_2(x['petal_length'], x['sepal_width'], 3), axis=1)
```

How can I use `multiprocessing` for `function_2` which takes more inputs than 1?

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/python-multiprocessing-pool-map-for-multiple-arguments) is helpful. However,  don't think `pool` is the right approach if you can write your function using vectorize numpy/pandas functions.

Comment: Thanks @QuangHoang. Yes pool is not great when vectorization is possible. However, my real function is quite complex, working with simulations and predictions and I am not sure if I would be able to use vectorized numpy/pandas functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a cleaner answer to this, but I typically would do the following:

```
import itertools
def function_2(input):
    val_1, val_2, param_ = input
    return [param_] * round(val_1 + val_2)

iris['test_2'] = pool.map(function_2, zip(iris['petal_length'], iris['sepal_width'], itertools.repeat(3)))
```

You may have to apply some additional formatting of your inputs to do it correctly.